# Apache (OWA) Reverse Proxy on Windows 2012 R2 stops responding

Tags: apache-2.4, windows-server-2012-r2, reverse-proxy

Recently I've swapped our old ISA Server with an Apache Reverse Proxy. The ISA Server only did reverse proxying for Exchange OWA. Because of this it was rather simple on my first thought.
After I figured out that this task is a bigger one to accomplish (and after some late-night hair tearing) I have a running reverse proxy. And hooray it's also able to process Active-Sync.
Now to my error: This Reverse Proxy simply shuts (neglects incoming queries) down for 15 Minutes randomly. It is running constantly though and not crashing. Instead, as I've already said, it's not responding when opened in a browser. We have a VSS backup solution running, but the point of failure is not in the time range of our backup running.

If you want I can provide logs, but keep in mind that these error logs can get over 200 MB a day, due to this not standard implementation of Active-Sync from Windows.
Below you'll find my config and versions of my Windows and Apache. If you need anything more I can provide, please feel free to let me know.
Apache Version: 2.4.16
Windows Server 2012 R2

```
ProxyRequests Off
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.200:443>
  ServerName webmail.example.com:443
  Header always set X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
  Header set Server Apache
  Header unset X-AspNet-Version
  Header unset X-OWA-Version
  Header unset X-Powered-By
  Header unset WWW-Authenticate
  Header add WWW-Authenticate "Basic=realm=mail.example.com"
  Header add WWW-Authenticate "Basic realm=webmail.example.com"
  Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary

  RequestHeader unset Expect early

  ProxyPreserveHost on
  SSLProxyEngine on
  RewriteEngine on
  SSLEngine on

  SSLProxyVerify none
  SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
  SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
  SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off
  SSLCertificateFile "C:/apache24/conf/ssl/webmail.example.com.crt"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:/apache24/conf/ssl/webmail.example.com.key"

  SetEnv proxy-initial-not-pooled 1
  SetEnv proxy-nokeepalive 1
  SetEnv force-proxy-request-1.0 1
  SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" value BrowserMSIE
  SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown downgrade-1.0 force-respone-1.0

  BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" nokeepalive ssl-UNClean-shutdown downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
  BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-UNClean-shutdown

  RewriteRule ^/$ https://192.168.0.200/owa/ [P,L]
  RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://192.168.0.200/$1 [P]

  AddDefaultCharset ISO-8859-1
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks for helping.